# framework using page Object gem - bundle as a gem

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I would like to create a framework using the ruby page object gem. The idea is simple. I want to seperate the common re-uable components under framework project and then finally bundle all these as a gem. 
All the project related codes ( pages and all the other stuffs ) will go inside the project. 
The good thing i am looking at is re-usability within different project. Also the developer can develop the scripts much faster way.

Now the question is : Can i move the hooks file inside the framework ? If so, If i add this framework gem to a project, will that automatically pick the hooks file inside the gem? The reason why i am thinking like this is almost every team here uses the same hooks file and there are no changes at all.

The whole idea is DRY. Any other ideas are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I did this for a team a while back. The solution we ended up with was a file called global_hooks.rb which had a method define_hooks. When you called the method, it would define the hooks just like you would in the hooks file. Because it was all in a method, it wasn't evaluated until called in the hooks file.

global_hooks.rb:

```
def define_hooks
  Before do
    #do something before
  end
end
```

hooks.rb:

```
require 'global_hooks'
define_hooks
```

Comment: Thanks Dane for the comment. That comment was certainly helpful. But what i am looking for is ... A framework built using page object model with all the necessary automation libraries and the users can just use this so that we can minimal their initial project effort. I think this will defenitely save lot of time.

Comment: Sorry, I read through and saw "now the question is" and thought you meant that was the entire question. What kind of reusable components are you looking for?

Comment: Are there common elements on pages? Like menus or navigation? Are there custom web controls like calendars? Or is there business logic about how you want to deal with elements or the data you want to use or see?

Comment: I am looking for a complete framework library. It should have API Module, Database Module & Mainframe emulator. I know different gems are available outside, but it would be better if I handle as a seperate project. Along with this, i am trying to include the Page Object Model common things like hooks file, env and other stuffs.